# fails with ZipArchive

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

i will create a Zip Archive with the PHP Class. But it still not working.
It comes no fail and the response is 1. He don't create the Zip-File.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('qr_img/'.'ab387bas.zip'.'', ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile($file, 'screen.png');
    $zip->close();
}
```

know's everyone the answer ?

Comment: have a look at this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381142/ziparchive-open-error-in-php/15381350#15381350 the response "1" is actually an error code, look for it on the internet.

Comment: Here it is, at the bottom of the page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.constants.php if $res == 1 it means `Multi-disk zip archives not supported`

Comment: Thank you, but what can i do about this ?

Comment: if the zip is generated by yourself, just generate it so it's not multi-disk. If the zip archive is supposed to be uploaded by users, show them a message saying the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$file_names` is the array of files which are you want to add in the zip.

```
 function zipFile($file_names,$archive_file_name)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    //create the file and throw the error if unsuccessful
    if ($zip->open($archive_file_name, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE )!==TRUE) {

    }

    //add each files of $file_name array to archive
    foreach($file_names as $files)
    {
    //  $zip->addFile($files,$files);
        $zip->addFromString(basename($files),  file_get_contents($files));
    }
    $zip->close();


}
```